# Typescript function: Return statement in a while loop doesn't work as expected

Tags: typescript, function, while-loop, return

I have a depth first search written in Typescript the function works as I would expect and traverses to every connected node. However I have a return statement in a while loop and I want the function to return if the id of the current node matches a target id. It is just a number equals a number. The condition is met as expected but the function does not return true it returns once the while condition is complete. Is this Typescript behaviour? Is there a way to make it work as I would expect ending the while loop and returning true from the function?

```
function dfs(graph: any, node: any,nodedata: any,target?: any){
    var stack: any[] = []
    var visited: any[] = []
    var visiting = null

    stack.push(node)
    visited.push(node)

    while(stack.length > 0){
        visiting = stack.pop()
        var connectedNodes = graph.getConnectedNodes(visiting.id,"to")
        connectedNodes.forEach(function(itm: any){
            var check_node = nodedata.get(itm)
                console.log("check_node",check_node.id,"target",target.id)

                // Here is the problem everything works but the return true never happens
                if(check_node.id == target.id){
                    console.log('Condition met')
                    return true
                }
                // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            if(!visited.includes(check_node)){
                visited.push(check_node)
                stack.push(check_node)
            }
        })
    }
    
return false
}
```

I would expected to get true as I set it up so the condition is true. I get 'Condition met' so the conditional triggered but it just drops through and returns false. As I stated earlier the function works just not the return from within the while. I can work around it but it seems a little weird.

```
// Here is the problem everything works but the return true never happens
if(check_node.id == target.id){
   console.log('Condition met')
   return true // Never happens
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Dumb code to check the result

```
var checkdfs = dfs(network,nodes.get(1),nodes,nodes.get(4))
if(checkdfs){
   console.log('It returned true')
}else{
   console.log('It returned false')
}
```

```
check_node 2 target 4
check_node 5 target 4
check_node 3 target 4
check_node 4 target 4
Condition met
It returned false
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `true` from within the callback of your [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function. This return value doesn't get returned to the outer scope.

In addition, you also lose the benefit of having an early return when a matching value is found, as `forEach()` will happily keep iterating, regardless of what value you return from its callback.

The easiest solution is to use a standard `for` loop:

```
for (let itm: any of connectedNodes) {
  // ...
  if(check_node.id == target.id) {
    return true;
  }
  // ...
}
```

If, for whatever reason, you prefer to stick to a functional paradigm, you can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
return connectedNodes.some((itm: any) => check_node.id === nodedata.get(itm).id);
```